# How to setup Constructor options in Buefy while using CDN?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome-5, buefy

I'm new to Buefy and Vue.

I'm using the following libraries through CDN: bulma0.9.3 vue2.6.14 buefy0.9.13 fontawesome5.15.4

Two files `index.html` and `index.js` are being used.

I'm tried to set the `defaultIconPack` to fontawesome globally by following the instructions given at [Constructor options - Buefy documentation](https://buefy.org/documentation/constructor-options/). But the icons in `index.html` defaults to `mdi` and not to fontawesome.

**index.js**

```
Vue.use(Buefy, {
        defaultIconPack: 'fas'
    });
let vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
    data: {
        data: [],
        columns: []
    },
    mounted: function () {
        document.getElementById('main').classList.add('is-active');
    },
    methods: {},
    computed: {}
})
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.$buefy.config, like this:

```
mounted:function () {
    this.$buefy.config.setOptions({defaultIconPack: 'fas'});
    document.getElementById('main').classList.add('is-active');
},
```